# Metrics for questions and answers

Tags: feature-request

I was wondering if there were anyway to have automatic stats on points/answer, points/question, etc on the site.  I didn't see it, so apologies if its there, but I think it would be beneficial to introduce some metrics into the user profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not automatic, but you can get numbers like this from the [SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com). For example, I have a [query for top users by average answer score](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/47595/top-users-by-average-answer-vote), and you can also browse other queries that people have created.

Other than that, try checking [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) to see if this has been requested there - it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: When I went there I didn't see a log in through Facebook, just curious as to why that site doesn't have that option

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141685/no-facebook-log-in-for-stackexchange-data-explorer

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

The [Stack Exchange user leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues) provide a limited contestesque view of user activities.